# Cannot disable debugging-AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, debugging, apk

I want to disable debugging so i can upload my android game, but "android:debugging" is nowhere to be seen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Upload a bundle to google play. Apk should be signed before to upload. https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that the `Development build` checkbox is empty in `Build Settings` window before creating the build.

[image: unity3d build settings dialog]